# What shape was the greenhouse?

Tags: riddle

> There was a small greenhouse.
>
> Inside it was a white house.
>
> The white house as flooded.

What was the shape of the greenhouse, and why?

Options:

1. Circular
2. Square
3. Triangular
4. Hexagonal
5. Star

Comment: what does as flooded mean? is that a typo

Comment: @enigmaticcard It means covered or submerged (a place or area) in water.

Comment: I think @enigmaticcard means, should it be "was flooded" or "is flooded" or "has flooded" or ... ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 'greenhouse' is:

> **1. Circular**

Because it is:

> A **young green coconut**. It is *small* (you can hold it in your hand) and *green* on the outside. The inside of it is white, and within this 'white house' is [coconut water](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coconut_water) (i.e.full of water = '*flooded*').

Answer (score 1):

I choose

> 1 (circular)

because

> I think that the green house is the Earth.

Comment: What's the white house then?

Comment: I think that the white house is an ordinary house, maybe it's so crowded then.

Comment: there's no ordinary house inside earth

Answer (score 0):

I think the greenhouse is

> An aquarium, so it shape is circular.

The white house is

> A decoration at the bottom of the aquarium

Comment: Nope, that's not it.